# Web scraping a dynamic content with Android

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Simple story here: I've written a Java app that reads dynamic content from a website using Selenium, parses it and saves it to a remote database. For convenience, I would prefer doing this from an Android device. AFAIK I can't really run Selenium on Android, so what are my options? Requirements: should run on Android 11 and allow scrolling a website (needed to trigger 'load more' event).